# Enabling an API loading forever

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-assist-api

I'm trying to enable the Embedded Assistant API, but it is just loading indefinitely.

The URL is:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/overview?project=myprojectishere

Anyone else experiencing difficulties?

Comment: Yes, several times, page refresh usually works.

Comment: The same issue for me, enable billing stuck loading

Answer (score 3):

A similar issue was happening to me (but for Billing) and this is how I fixed it...

**Problem**

When I was asked to enable billing to use a GCP service, I was able to select an existing billing account. However, when I tried to `Set Account`, it would be stuck on an infinite load.

---

**Solution**

As for the fix:

1. Open the left hamburger menu and select `Billing`.
2. `Link a Billing Account` to your project.
3. Select your existing Billing Account and `Set Account`.

In my case, I got the following error because I reached the quota for how many projects can enable billing.
[image: Unable to enable billing error]

You can do two things:

1. Request a Quota Increase
2. Create a new Billing Account and add it to your project

In my case, I requested a Quota Increase which took <5 minutes to process.
I tried adding Billing to my account again, this time it worked instantly and loading wasn't stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it works for me.

[Many Google APIs require billing to be enabled](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158867?hl=en) since they charge you for usage. So, you will want to double check that you have a Billing account created and associated with the Google Cloud Platform project you're using prior to enabling the API.

> To enable billing for your project:
>
> - Go to the [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
> - From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
> - Open the console left side menu and select **Billing**.
> - Click **Enable billing**. (If billing is already enabled then this option isn't available.)
> - If you don't have a billing account, create one.
> - Select your location, fill out the form, and click **Submit and enable billing**.